# Interrupting the execution of a method

Tags: c++

I have a case where I need to call a method that runs for infinite time on specific occasions: `obj.run()`

The program will have a callback that should start this method or stop it based on a received message.

How can that be achieved?
Obs.: `obj` doesn't seem to have a destructor and the function is meant to stop only when killing the process.

Comment: It is in C++, the method was a mistake.

Comment: Anyhow, what does "interrupt" mean in this case? How is the decision to interrupt made? Should the function continue execution later? Is the decision made by the execution of the function itself? If so C++20 coroutines might help. Is the decision made from another thread? Then you need some cooperative signaling mechanism to ask the other thread to suspend execution. In any case, please provide some details, a bit of code preferably.

Comment: From what you describe it seems like `obj.run()` is not something you implemented yourself. In that case you can try starting a separate thread with running this method, and kill it from the main thread when you need to

Comment: What's wrong with killing the process? How is the desired state of your system different from the state with the process killed?

Comment: @Alexey, I will try doing that. Seems to be the best option

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I don't have control over the functions called within this method. I want to have this method running for a specific amount of time, triggered by a received message

Comment: Look like a scenario where use threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using `boost::thread::interrupt`

like in the code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/86a992ea1700aa634657f840f3cfcafc)

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ThreadFunction() {
  int counter = 0;

  for (;;) {
    cout << "thread iteration " << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

    try {
      // Sleep and check for interrupt.
      // To check for interrupt without sleep,
      // use boost::this_thread::interruption_point()
      // which also throws boost::thread_interrupted
      boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    } catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {
      cout << "Thread is stopped" << endl;
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  // Start thread
  boost::thread t(&ThreadFunction);

  // Wait for Enter
  char ch;
  cin.get(ch);

  // Ask thread to stop
  t.interrupt();

  // Join - wait when thread actually exits
  t.join();
  cout << "main: thread ended" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```